# Searching images within region/area and reacting based on them

Tags: python

Total beginner here.

In this program, I am trying to "monitor" a specific area on my screen. There are several images entering the region (from the right side) with random frequency. (Basically, a "simple" rhythm" game).
I have tried pyautoguy.locateOnScreen, but it was way too slow even though I set the region into a small square. I don't think I can use pixels because the images entering the region are all the same color but have different symbols on them, and each relates to a keyboard letter.

In this last attempt, I tried this:

1. Create an "endless" while loop, in which I make a screenshot of my desired region/location(bbox), and within that endless loop, I use IF and several ELIF in which I use pyautogui.locate to search a specific image (tiny screenshot of the symbol) on the bigger screenshot made by ImageGrab. I have several images, and each image has a different keyboard response.

I got to about 75-80% accuracy, but when the symbols are close to each other, it always misses. When I checked at which rate the whole loop runs, I get to like 2.9 runs per second, sometimes 4-5. Could anyone give me some pointers on how to double the speed (if that's even possible?)
Thanks!

```
import time
import pyautogui
import os
import pydirectinput
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
import time

start_time = time.time()
x = 1 # frames
counter = 0

bbox=(588,786,635,944) #my region I am searching in



def detect(imgDir, haystackImage, confidence=0.90, cache=True):
    if (pyautogui.locate(os.path.join('images', imgDir), haystackImage, confidence=confidence)) is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:

    ScreenGrab = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
    ScreenName = f"screenshot"
    Path = f"./images/{ScreenName}.png"
    ScreenGrab.save(Path)
    hsImage = Image.open('D:/PY/images/screenshot.png')

    if detect('D:/PY/images/a.png', hsImage, cache=True):
        pydirectinput.press('a')
        continue
    elif detect('D:/PY/images/b.png', hsImage, cache=True):
        pydirectinput.press('b')
        continue

    elif detect('D:/PY/images/c.png', hsImage, cache=True):
        pydirectinput.press('c')
        continue
    elif detect('D:/PY/images/d.png', hsImage, cache=True):
        pydirectinput.press('d')
        continue
    elif detect('D:/PY/images/e.png', hsImage, cache=True):
        pydirectinput.press('e')
        continue
    else:
         pass

counter+=1 #counter for my runs per second
    if (time.time() - start_time) > x :
        print("FPS: ", counter / (time.time() - start_time))
        counter = 0
        start_time = time.time()
```

Comment: you can use `time()` to check which part takes more time. I think the biggest problem can be `grab()` and you can't change it.

Comment: I don't know if `locate` can work with image loaded to memory because this can make code faster - you could load images only once.

Comment: if `grab()` gives `Image` then don't save it on file and don't read it from file bacause work with hard drive is slow. And if it gives `numpy.array` then there is method to convert it directly to `Image`.